# Google Login iframe is rendering differently on two similar pages

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-signin

I have two similar pages (actually they are the same page, but in two different environments) and I'm calling the function `google.accounts.id.renderButton` for get the token and link it with my site account.

The backend is working well, but when the page loads, the generated iframe structure (inside the button ) looks different in one of the environments:

Environment 1:
[image]

Environment 2:
[image]

As you can see, the Environment 2 iframe has a `div` filled with another stuff, while in the other the `div` is empty(and thats is right). The result on screen looks like this for Environment 2:

[image]

The Google button is overriding the two other buttons, and duplicating the label inside of it.

Has anyone faced this problem before?

The code that make this happen is this:

```
    var elementLink = document.getElementById('googleLinkBtn');
    google.accounts.id.renderButton(
        elementLink,
        { theme: "outfilled", size: "large", shape: "square", width: "300",  click_listener: attachLinkButton }
    );
```

Edit:
I was looking at the Chrome console while the page was loading and I noticed these two errors:
[image]

The funny thing is that there's two buttons on the function, the first one is loading OK (in another html element).

Comment: Does it also happen on an incognito window ?

Comment: Yes, it happen on an incognito window too.